# Reading a .txt file containing a 2D matrix, fscanf only grabbing first data element from .txt file

Tags: c, pointers, file-io

I am trying to read a 2D matrix from a .txt file into a dynamically sized 2D array. The matrix in the .txt file is tab delimited and could be of any size but for simplicity, we have:

```
1 2 3  
4 5 6  
7 8 9
```

I parse the file for a row and column count, dynamically create an empty 2D array `**dynamicMatrix` using `malloc()` and try to fill said array with data from my file. 
Here is the code i have:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>

/* File Names for IO */
#define MATRIX2 "matrix2.txt"

int rowCounter(FILE *filePtr)
{
    int rowCount = 1;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(filePtr)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            rowCount++;
        }
    }
    rewind(filePtr);
    //printf("row count:%d\n", rowCount);
    return rowCount;
}

int colCounter(FILE *filePtr)
{
    int colCount = 1;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(filePtr)) != '\n')
    {
        //printf("ch was: %c\n", ch);
        if (ch == '\t')
        {
            colCount++;
        }
    }
    rewind(filePtr);
    //printf("col count:%d\n", colCount);
    return colCount;
 }

int **matrixConstructor(FILE *filePtr)
{
    int rowCount = rowCounter(filePtr);
    int colCount = colCounter(filePtr);
    int **dynamicMatrix;
    dynamicMatrix = malloc(rowCount * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        dynamicMatrix[i] = malloc(colCount * sizeof(int));
    }
    return dynamicMatrix;
}

void populateMatrixFromFile(FILE *filePtr, int **dynamicMatrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCounter(filePtr); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colCounter(filePtr); j++)
        {
            fscanf(filePtr, "%d", &dynamicMatrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void matrixPrinter(FILE *filePtr, int **dynamicMatrix)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<colCounter(filePtr); j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<rowCounter(filePtr); i++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", dynamicMatrix[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    /* File Pointers and Open Files to Read */
    FILE *fpMatrixIN2 = fopen(MATRIX2, "r");

    /* Check File Pointers for Null, Exit if Null */
    if (fpMatrixIN2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("One or more files failed to be found. Please make sure they are in the same directory as the executable.\n");
        system("pause"); 
        exit(1); //shut down program to avoid crash
    }

    /* Empty Arrays of Appropriate Lengths to store Matrices from Files */
    int **dynamicMatrix2 = matrixConstructor(fpMatrixIN2);

    populateMatrixFromFile(fpMatrixIN2, dynamicMatrix2);
    matrixPrinter(fpMatrixIN2, dynamicMatrix2);

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem i am running into is that `fscanf(filePtr, "%d", &dynamicMatrix[i][j])` seems to only be reading the the first int from my file, so my 3x3 dynamicMatrix is filled with 1's. I am not sure why this is happening as my understanding is that `fscanf()` should read in an int to the array then move forward reading the second, third and so on.

Expected output from printing `**dynamicMatrix`:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Actual output from printing `**dynamicMatrix`:

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

I have been yanking my hair out over this so an extra set of eyes to help find the problem would be greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT**
As both `@user3386109` and `@f igura` mentioned, the issue was that i called `rowCounter()` and `colCounter()` in my for loop in `populateMatrixFromFile` which kept rewinding the file pointer every iteration of the loop, thus causing `fscanf()` to only read 1 every time. I changed the code to call `rowCounter()` and `colCounter()` in main, then pass their values to my functions instead.

Comment: Check the return value of `fscanf`, if it isn't 1, then `fscanf` failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in `populateMatrixFromFile` calls the `rowCounter()` and `colCounter()` functions in the loops. Not only does that waste a lot of time, but it also `rewinds` the file on every iteration of the loop. It's best to call `rowCounter()` and `colCounter()` exactly ***once*** in `main` and then pass the counts to the other functions.

Comment: So i updated my code to call `rowCounter()` and `colCounter()` in main and pass their values into my functions and that gave me my expected output. So due to my rewinds in those functions, when i called `fscanf` it would be at the beginning of the file again?

Comment: thank you for the help! I added an edit to the OP with a problem description and solution that you helped find.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is your rowCounter and colCounter. More specifically, you call the them in the for loop cause you keep rewinding and then of course you can only print "1".
Try pass the rowCount and colCount as arguments to populateMatrixFromFile and matrixPrinter.

Comment: @F igura, thanks for the help too! I added an edit to the OP with a problem description and solution that you helped find.